# Triggers execution order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I've a doubt about triggers execution order.
To explain it I will use an example:
I've a trigger on table *myTable*, so, inside this trigger there is an update on *myTable*, this throw another instance of the same trigger(I will call the first instance '*A*' and this new instance '*B*'), now the question is:
will the instance *B* started in asyncronous way and the instance *A* continue the execution, or will be the instance *B* started and the instance *A* will wait for *B* completion?

I hope I explained myself

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Why would you want to do this to yourself?  Triggers should be used sparingly: they have subtle but possibly deep impact on things, and I can not think of a good reason to have a trigger update the table which would re-invoke the trigger.

Comment: It's just a curiosity about triggers execution, but there's a similar situation on a work already created

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if the inner trigger (B) doesn't block the outer trigger (A).
The reason for this would be Determinism - if B runs asynchronously, it's possible that it could complete before *or* after A, and if they both try to update the same field, you couldn't guarantee what the end result would be.

Even if B did run asynchronously, the statement that triggered it would only return *after* all the triggers had finished. This is due to the [Atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) and [Consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Consistency) principles of DBMSs.

There is a setting that you can use to determine whether a trigger can set off another trigger: [Nested Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option)